# Add Viewpager in fragment

Tags: android-layout, android-fragments, android-studio, fragment

Hello I created my app using fragments and I need to implement a `viewpager` in one of them (In that `viewpager` user can swipe between different information (about using the application that I am currently developing. I assume there will be 3 to 5 views with text and details)). Bellow is the code to current fragment. Can you guys give me an idea what would be the best way to implement `Viewpager` in fragment with let's say 3 views and every view will have like 3 or 4 things on it(Imageview,Textview etc). I have already implemented `Viewpager` in other activity but this is my first time I'm implementing it inside a fragment. What's the logic about it. I tried using google but it sound to complicated.

```
public class AboutSectionFragment extends Fragment   {


    // The onCreateView method is called when Fragment should create its View object hierarchy,
    // either dynamically or via XML layout inflation.
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.about_section, parent, false);

        // Defines the xml file for the fragment
        return rootView ;
    }

    // This event is triggered soon after onCreateView().
    // Any view setup should occur here.  E.g., view lookups and attaching view listeners.
    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used ViewPager inside a fragment and its working fine for me.

Fragment class

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_content, container, false);
        fragments = getFragmentsList();
        pagerAdapter = new HomeViewPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager(),fragments);
        ViewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.Home_View_Pager);
        ViewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);

 private ArrayList<Fragment> getFragmentsList(){
    fragments = new ArrayList<>();
    fragments.add(HomeViewPagerFragment.getInstance());
    fragments.add(HomeViewPagerFragment.getInstance());
    fragments.add(HomeViewPagerFragment.getInstance());
    fragments.add(HomeViewPagerFragment.getInstance());
    fragments.add(HomeViewPagerFragment.getInstance());

    return fragments;
}
```

ViewPager Fragment Class

```
public class HomeViewPagerFragment extends Fragment {
    public static HomeViewPagerFragment getInstance(){
        HomeViewPagerFragment fragment = new HomeViewPagerFragment();
        return fragment;
    }
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_pager_fragment_layout,container,false);
        return view;
    }
}
```